# What is correct "Blazing Fast Speed" or "Blazingly Fast Speed"?

Tags: adjectives, american-english, adverbs

Which is correct? "Blazing Fast Speed" or "Blazingly Fast Speed"?

In my opinion, the latter because one can't say, for one, "Amazing Fast Speed", right?

Admittedly NY Times use it a lot but...:

[NY Times search for 'blazing fast' (via Google)](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Anytimes.com+%22blazing+fast%22&oq=site%3Anytimes.com+%22blazing+fast%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.818j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I kinda like _Fastly Blazing Speed_. It's distinctive.

Comment: It would be good if somebody with access to different corpora could check this, but [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blazing+fast%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cblazingly+fast%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C+blazing+fast%3Aeng_us_2012%2C+blazingly+fast%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cblazingly%20fast%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cblazing%20fast%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cblazingly%20fast%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0) seems to indicate this is one of those places where American and British English differ.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Either *blazing* or *blazingly* could be valid.

We can use *blazing* to intensify *fast*, just as something can be *burning hot* or *sopping wet*, which sound redundant but are idiomatic. *Blazingly*, the usual adverbial form, would of course work in this manner.

We could alternatively read *blazing* and *fast* as parallel descriptors for *speed*, just as we can have *soothing sweet tea* or an *amazing technicolor dreamcoat*.

Answer (score 2):

There are several intensifiers that end *-ing*, most of them swearing. I read *blazing* as replacing a similarly formed word which the NY Times would not deign to print.

Comment: So you imply `Blazingly` is more grammatically correct.

Comment: It is interesting that they put it in quotes. But as regards the word which the NYT would not deign to print, would that not have to be f***ingly-fast? Or do swear words stop with ..ing?

Comment: You probably read it this way because "blazing fast" is an Americanism. I certainly don't.

Comment: @WS2: I've never encountered _f***ingly_ as an intensifier, as far as I can remember. Or _fr***ingly_ or _s***ingly_.

Comment: @WS2: Insisting that grammar requires *-ly* on adverbial intensifiers is just bloodily wrong.

Comment: @PeterShor Or even justly bloodily wrong!